# Cannot update ListView from another Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a main-activity that contains a search bar and a search-activity. When I enter a string in the search bar and hit return, the search-activity is called. I am trying to update the listview in main-activity from search-activity, but that does not work. whats wrong? thx

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
static List<String> valueList;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    valueList = new ArrayList<String>();

    MainActivity.valueList.add("eins");
    MainActivity.valueList.add("zwei");
    MainActivity.valueList.add("drei");
    MainActivity.valueList.add("vier");
    MainActivity.valueList.add("fünf");
    MainActivity.valueList.add("sechs");

    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MainActivity.valueList);

    final ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
        { }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    return true;
}
```

}

```
public class SearchableActivity extends Activity {
ListView lv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_searchable);

    android.util.Log.v("my_search", "onCreate()");
    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    android.util.Log.v("my_search", "onNewIntent()");
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

        android.util.Log.v("my_search", "handleIntent()");
        android.util.Log.v("my_search", "Query: "+query);

        TextView tv;
        tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_searchable);
        tv.setText("Suche nach: "+query);
        doMySearch(query);
    }
}

public void doMySearch(String query)
{
    List<String> valueList_new = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(String s : MainActivity.valueList) {
        if(s.contains(query)) {
            android.util.Log.v("my_search", "gefunden: "+s);
            valueList_new.add(s);
        }
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, valueList_new);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    finish();
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I wanted that doMySearch fills the listview with content of valueList_new. But the listview is still the same :(

Comment: if u are using another activity just to update the main activity then why dont u use onActivityResult

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html -- this tells me that i have to add a new activity for the search

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this option is not the best way but that how I solved it once.
Try to keep an attribute (a `public static List`) in the MainActivity with the values you want to show.

Now, set up your apadter everytime the activity comes to foreground:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){

    adapter = new ExpandListAdapter(MainActivity.this, valueList);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    super.onResume();
}
```

So you just need to edit your valueList from SearchableActivity and the ListView will be automatically updated.

If you don't like public attributes, you can implement a superActivity that contains a `Protected static List`. The both activities should inherit from the super.

But anyway, can't you handle the intent directly from inside the MainActivity?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this code

```
public void doMySearch(String query)
                {
                    List<String> valueList_new = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < MainActivity.valueList.size(); i++) {
                        if((valueList.get(i).contains(query)))
                        {
                             valueList_new.add(valueList.get(i));
                        }
                    }
                        }
```

Comment: in my logs the values are correct. just the adapter does not get set correctly.

Comment: just add a for loop. it will add all your value to list

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update listview by New another Adapter. 
ListView only has 1 adapter which is the first time of setting dapter for listview.
To update listview, you need to update data of your adapter. 
Refer: [Update ListView items from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24447511/update-listview-items-from-another-class)