# Update ListView items from another class

Tags: java, android

I have an issue when I try to update my `listview` values. I have a Custom Adapter that is composed by edit text. When i click on an edit text I show a dialog (that is in another class) and pass to him same values like position, arralist and other.

In the dialog class I've this method

```
public void updateValue(String newValue) {
    MyObject object = arrayList.get(position);
        object.valueFile = newValue;
    arrayList.set(position, object);
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(context, 0, arrayList);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This method works because the new values is correctly insert into the array list but the text of the edit text is not updated BUT it only updates when I scroll, and then I go back to that editt text. Why? How can I fix? Where is the problem?

Comment: not a good practice but really easy you can make your adapter a public static class variable and do MyClass.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); Another way create an interface a good way but write more code

Comment: Why is not a good practice?

Comment: because static fields are known to be the source of many bugs they are present throughtout the app lifecycle. Cannot be garbage collected

Comment: What would be a better solution than this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot New() your adapter at the second time. The adapter can only New() one time. 
If you want to update listview, you need to update data in your arrayList

```
ArrayList<yourType> arrayList = new ArrayList<yourType>();
//Init data for your arrayList
//...
//Init your adapter
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(context, 0, arrayList);

//update item of listview
public void updateValue(String newValue) {
    arrayList.get(position).valueFile = newValue;
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: ArrayList values are already updated with set() method. I need to notify the changes at the adapter.

Comment: you need to make sure arrayList in updateValues method and arrayList when New() adapter (at the first time) is the same (same memory). And try to remove MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(...)

Comment: I added my code to show how I update a item in list view